# Docker: The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) was not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, .net-core, containers

I have an existing dotnet core 3.1 web app that builds and deploys to an azure app service.  it works fine.   I am trying to containerize the app.

the build is fine, but when the container runs it gives me

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

my docker

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY myreports/*.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myreports.dll"]
```

I've tried a variety of docker images(inc dotnet/core) and its the same.
my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>myreports</RootNamespace>
    <UserSecretsId>ed68b972-ed89-4115-8e6c-5f0d032efa4d</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FastReport.Core3.Web" Version="2021.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" Version="2.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.9">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <!--PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.14.0" /-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" Version="1.6.0-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I suspect its this
    `<PackageReference Include="FastReport.Core3.Web" Version="2021.3.0" />`

But its required as its core to the project.   What gets me is that my config in the (working) app settings is:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your project is targeting .NET Core 3.1 but your Dockerfile is referencing `6.0` tags, which refers to .NET 6. A .NET Core 3.1 app won't be able to run in a 6.0 runtime container. You should update your Dockerfile to reference `3.1` instead of `6.0`.

#### Update

Since there's also a dependency on the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App framework, you'll need to manually add that framework into the runtime. By default, the runtime image only contains the `Microsoft.NETCore.App`.

However, the sdk image does contain the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App framework. This allows you to use an sdk container to *build* a project that has a Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App framework dependency. You just can't run, by default, in the runtime container because it's very atypical to run an app in a container that has such a dependency.

What this all means is that you can copy the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App framework from the sdk to the runtime container which should resolve your issue. I've updated your Dockerfile to include `COPY` instruction which does this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY myreports/*.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1
COPY --from=build ["C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App", "C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App/"]
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myreports.dll"]
```

Comment: 3.1 or 6.0, same issue

Answer (score 0):

As the package name indicates it is a windows dependant component. Try running your application on a windows container not linux.

Comment: What package name leads you to suspect that the application is Windows dependent? I can't spot anything in the .csproj file or the dockerfile that suggests that.

Comment: @omajid I think package "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" belongs to .NET Desktop Runtime. But your container doesn't have that runtime. You should install this runtime to your container before running it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am wondering (and I think the question asker is too) why is there a dependnecy on that in the first place. This is an ASP.NET Core project with no apparent dependencies on anything Desktop related?

Comment: It is running in a windows container

Comment: If you build your project locally and open up the `obj/project.assets.json` file, you might be able to find what's causing the dependency on Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.

Comment: Thanks @MattThalman , that confirms it, "FastReport.Net.Pro/2021.3.0"

So the magic question, how to I get it into the container.  or which image do I use?

Like, which image does the app service run off?

Comment: @RobinHalabicki I've ansewered questions without being sure. I've had a similar problem regarding some windows.drawing library requiring a linux library called gdiplus. I had to add a command to dockerfile that downloads and installs the missing dll. So you can try to install that missing dependency or runtime on your dockerfile.

Comment: stupid question: how do you download and install in the docker

Comment: @RobinHalabicki it's easy sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y libgdiplus (on linux containers)

Comment: its a windows container

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to resolve this by changing the final image to :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

Comment: This may work but comes with tremendous cost. That image is intended for *building* .NET *Framework* projects. It is several GBs in size compared to just 300 MB for the 6.0 runtime image. I've updated my answer to indicate how you can fix the issue using the runtime image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71041288/3174766

Comment: This is where I'm confused, which docker image (assuming all is 6.0) do I use for the build and which for the runtime.

Comment: upgrading to 6.0 and using runtime (as mentioned) 
```FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
```
gets:
```The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found.

  - No frameworks were found.```

So confused

Answer (score 0):

Following your answer on changing the image to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

If you did not change your csproj you now have a .NET Core 3.1 app running on .NET 4.8. This *could* lead to subtle runtime problems. (citation needed)

I would strongly suggest upgrading your csproj to .NET 6 since .NET 3.1 is running out of support in some months anyways.

I might be mistaken but the first step would be to change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` and of course follow an upgrade guide online https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thanks, the issue is even upgrading the target framework to 6 didn't resolve the problem until the runtime had the right framework to use Windows.Desktop.App